# Extracting text attributes using Tesseract hOCR

Tags: java, svg, fonts, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract (on windows) to extract text from scientific diagrams, e.g. plots, where there are many isolated words or numbers but no sentences or paragraphs. I then turn the HTML into SVG. This works well except that I cannot get

- font-size
- font-family
- xy-coordinate of text anchor
- text orientation (e.g. rotated Math.PI/2 for labelling graph axes)

I can get a rough font size from the bounding box but this depends on whether characters have ascenders or descenders. Thus all the lines below (in hOCR output) have the same font-family and size:

```
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_6' title="bbox 1177 491 1637 549">Herpetotherinae</span> 
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_13' title="bbox 1183 1179 1514 1228">Cathartidae</span>
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_35' title="bbox 1847 1742 1907 2077">Accipitridae</span>
```

span_1 has a descender (in "p") and a bbox y-height of 58, while span_2 has bbox height 49 (no descenders) and span_3 has bbox x-width of 60, showing the text is rotated. However the bbox by itself is not enough to position the text accurately or determine text orientation.

I would like to use Tess4J and use any API that would lead to getting these attributes.

If anyone has already written an SVG output from Tess4J I'd be grateful. (any code from me is F/OSS).

Comment: The lack of comments / answers prompts me to abandon tesseract and hack my own. Tesseract already has the problem of wrapped C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Font information isn't included in the the hOCR output by default, but it is available if desired.  You can turn it on by adding the following line to your `hocr` config file (or whichever config file you're using):

```
hocr_font_info 1
```

The same config variable can also be used on the command line (or, presumably, through the Tess4J wrapper).

With this turned on, the font name and size will be included in the output, e.g.

```
<span class='ocrx_word' id='word_3_21' title='bbox 946 1267 1121 1297; x_wconf 91; x_font Courier_New; x_fsize 9' dir='ltr'>without</span>
```

`x_font` is the font name Courier_New
`x_fsize` is the font size in points ie 9

Bold and italics will be indicated both in the font name and through the use of `<strong>` and `<em>` tags.